# How to pass conditional parameter in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-compose-appbar

I want to hide the **navigationIcon** but when I pass `null` or `Unit` the icon space remains visible, as can be seen in the image below.

[image: Menu preview]

```kotlin
@Composable
fun DefaultScaffold(
    title: String? = null,
    icon: ImageVector? = null,
    content: @Composable() () -> Unit
) {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = {
                    if (title != null) {
                        Text(text = "My Title")
                    }
                },
                navigationIcon = {
                    if (icon != null) {
                        IconButton(
                            onClick = {}
                        ) {
                            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Close, contentDescription = null)
                        }
                    } else Unit
                }
            )
        }
    ) {
        content()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Remove the parentheses that surround your conditional statement, then return `null` instead of `Unit` when you don't want to show the icon space.

So, it will become

```
navigationIcon = if (icon != null) {
    {
        IconButton(
            onClick = {}
        ) {
            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Close, contentDescription = null)
        }
    }
} else null
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use something like

```
navigationIcon = if (icon != null) {
    { /*... your code ..*/ }
} else null
```

but the constructor of [`TopAppBar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#TopAppBar(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp)) with `title` and `navigationIcon` parameters preserves the slots for a title and the navigation icon.
If you check the [source code](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/tools/dokka-devsite-plugin/+/master:testData/compose/source/androidx/compose/material/AppBar.kt;l=94?q=TopAppBar&ss=androidx%2Fplatform%2Ftools%2Fdokka-devsite-plugin:testData%2F) you can find:

```
if (navigationIcon == null) {
            Spacer(TitleInsetWithoutIcon)
        } else {
```

You should use the constructor with the [**`content`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#TopAppBar(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues,kotlin.Function1)) parameter, that has no restriction on content.
Then you can use something like:

```
    TopAppBar(
        content = {
            Row(Modifier.fillMaxHeight(), verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically){
                if (icon != null) {
                    IconButton(
                        onClick = {},
                    ) {
                        Icon(imageVector = icon, contentDescription = null)
                    }
                }
                if (title != null) {
                    ProvideTextStyle(value = MaterialTheme.typography.h6) {
                        CompositionLocalProvider(
                            LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.high,
                        ){
                            Text(text = title)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    )
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yeah makes sense

Comment: yeah, the trick was that compiler expected a nullable function, not just an expression. Good explanation, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
@Composable
fun DefaultScaffold(
    title: String? = null,
    icon: ImageVector? = null,
    content: @Composable() () -> Unit
) {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = {
                    if (title != null) {
                        Text(text = "My Title")
                    }
                },
                navigationIcon = {
                    if (icon != null) {
                        IconButton(
                            onClick = {}
                        ) {
                            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Close, contentDescription = null)
                        }
                    } else Icon(modifier = Modifier.width(0), imageVector = Icons.Filled.Close, contentDescription = null) // Add a Modifier
                }
            )
        }
    ) {
        content()
    }
}
```